# Ubuntu 18 Ethernet connected but not working

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, ethernet

I recently moved an SSD with ubuntu 18.04 to a new desktop and am having some issues with network connections.

I need a wired ethernet connection (there is no wifi card on the desktop). When I try to set up a dhcp connection, I get an IP assigned and the network settings indicate it is connected, however, there is a question mark over the network icon, and I am unable to ping 8.8.8.8 or anything similar. ifconfig and other network tools all indicate that it is connected as well. I cannot visit any sites through any browsers as well.

I can provide any other information needed, but I am relatively stuck. Not sure where to proceed from here, since it thinks it is connected.

**EDIT1:**
per request, here is the result of ip addr show

`eno1:<BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000 
link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/24 brd xxx.xxx.xxx.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eno1
valid_lft 1744sec preferred_lft 1744sec`

and ls -al /etc/resolve.conf

`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Jul 16 2018 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`

**EDIT2:** here is `dmesg | grep -e eno1 network:

`[    2.098345] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eno1: renamed from eth0
[    8.318280] e1000e: eno1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None`

**EDIT3:** make and model of desktop:

HP Z6 G4 Workstation

Product Number: 3RT74UP#ABA

Comment: Please edit your question to show: `ip addr show` We are interested in the ethernet interface only; not the loopback known as *lo*. Also show: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: @emielke Would you please be so kind as to provide the make and model of the desktop? If it is a homebuilt, the make and model of the motherboard would suffice; if factory-built, please get the model number from the sticker on back or bottom which also has the serial number, for 'models' on top or front are often just marketing names, not the complete model number needed to find the components in your system. Please click [edit] and add that information to your question.

Comment: Do `sudo ufw logging off` please to disable the UFW block logs in dmesg, then restart, and try the same thing again to get the dmesg output WITHOUT the ufw logs (because they literally SPAM the syslogs).

Comment: @ThomasWard done, see above.